# RSS feed of a tag by user

Tags: support, feed

I can subscribe by "tag" or by "user". What I want is RSS feed of a tag+user.

All the "MySQL" questions answered by user "Quassnoi".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible.

That being said, there are two existing options to get close:

- If you want to follow someone like that, there's a pretty high likelihood that if you follow the user feed, most of the answers posted will be of interest to you anyway.
- You can periodically check on [this search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a55159+%5bmysql%5d), which looks for posts (both questions and answers) by a specific user id within the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) tag. This user mostly posts answers anyway.