# Is there one rss feed for all unanswered questions from all Stack Exchange sites of a user?

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions, feed

Is there one rss feed for all unanswered questions from **all Stack Exchange sites** of **one** user?

Something like `http://stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A2748772+%5Bunanswered%5D`
I found a few previous questions useful...

1. [RSS feed of a tag by user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73428/rss-feed-of-a-tag-by-user)......This is limited to one site
2. [Add an RSS feed for unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42525/add-an-rss-feed-for-unanswered-questions)....Resolution provided here isn't valid anymore.